# Show gif image on Label within text

Tags: ios, swift3, animated-gif

We are developing an application for both Android and iOS. We got a problem when trying to display gif image(image from local) on `UILabel` within text like Skype message [here](https://youtu.be/3aUbzy7HChg).

On Android, we are using `AnimatedImageSpan` to display and it works. But on iOS, we can not find any way to do this. If you know how to resolve my problem, please tell me. Thanks.

Comment: Resolved: https://github.com/yuchuanfeng/CFGifEmotionDemo